# How to select a row in a dataframe in which one of the cell value is as close as possible to another predefined value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframes with many columns. I want the code to select the row in which one of its values is the closest possible to a predefined value. This predefined value is referred to feature B and is equal to 7.35
Example,

```
    Feature A        Feature B
       0.1              7.05
         1              7.15
       0.7              7.08
       0.9              7.34
       1.1              7.39
        1               7.30
```

the code should then select the entire row were feature B is equal to 7.34 because is the closest possible to my value.
It will never happen that the predefined value is exactly equal to a value in the feature B (so I cannot use if valueFeature B == predefined value) because I have many decimals so I need a way to extract the row with the value of feature B as similar as possible to that predefined value. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) to subtract the predefined value i.e `7.35` from the column `Feature B`, then take the absolute value using `abs` and finally find the index of closet value using [`Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
s = df.loc[df['Feature B'].sub(7.35).abs().idxmin()]
```

Result:

```
# print(s)

Feature A    0.90
Feature B    7.34
Name: 3, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

**If K is your the predefined value .And df is the dataset .**

> For example : if **K=7.35**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

#Here is the function
def closest_value(list, K):
    list = np.asarray(list) 
    index = (np.abs(list - K)).argmin() 
    return list[index] 
      
K = 7.35
x = closest_value(df['Feature B'], K)) 
#x stores the closest value
print(df[df['Feature B']==x])
#prints the all rows where Feature B has value closest to pre-defined value.
```